# Google login uses same account everytime users login

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I use OAuth to let users sign in to the android app via Google account. When the user taps the Google login button for the first time, it produces a dialog to choose the account. Again, when the user logs out and decides to login with different Google account, it doesn't prompt to choose the account, it logs in the account the user had chose the previous time

'

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    initialize();
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    ref=new Firebase("https://texter10c.firebaseio.com");

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in !");
            progressDialog.setTitle("Hang on!");
            progressDialog.show();

            ref.authWithPassword(emailField.getText().toString(), passwordField.getText().toString(), new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
                    Log.e("Authenticated","Authenticated");
                    getUserIdandLogin();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, firebaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    googleSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressDialog.setTitle("Contacting Google");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Logging you in");
            progressDialog.show();
            if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    });

}

private void getGoogleToken(){

    AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> task=new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            final String scopes="oauth2:"+"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"+" "+"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me";
            try {
                if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
                {
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
                googleAccessToken= GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(LoginActivity.this,Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient),scopes);
                Log.e("AccessToken",googleAccessToken+"");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (GoogleAuthException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            try {
                ref.authWithOAuthToken("google", googleAccessToken, new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticated(final AuthData authData) {
                        try {
                            Log.e("Firebase", "Google Authentication Success");
                            Log.e("Username", authData.getProviderData().get("displayName").toString());
                            Log.e("Id", authData.getProviderData().get("id").toString());


                            Firebase googleUserRef = ref.child("UserDetails/names/" + authData.getProviderData().get("id").toString());
                            Map<String, String> googleUserMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            googleUserMap.put("Username", authData.getProviderData().get("displayName").toString());
                            final String UserID = "GoogleUser" + authData.getProviderData().get("displayName") + authData.getProviderData().get("id");
                            googleUserMap.put("UserId", UserID);

                            googleUserRef.setValue(googleUserMap, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    dataStore.setCurrentUserName(authData.getProviderData().get("displayName").toString());
                                    dataStore.setCurrentUserID(UserID);
                                    storeDatainSharedPreferences();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DialogActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        catch (NullPointerException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                        Log.e("GogoleAuthFailed", firebaseError.getMessage());

                    }
                });
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e)
            {
                Log.e("Accesstoken problem",e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };
    task.execute();
}

public void getUserIdandLogin()
{
    dataStore.userDialogMap=new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
    dataStore.generatedChatIds=new ArrayList<>();
    Firebase refUser=ref.child("UserDetails/names");
    refUser.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
            try{
                if (map.get("Email").equals(emailField.getText().toString()))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Successfilly Logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dataStore.setCurrentUserName(map.get("Username"));
                    dataStore.setCurrentUserID(map.get("UserId"));
                    intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,DialogActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    storeDatainSharedPreferences();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

            }
            catch (NullPointerException e)
            {
                Log.e("NullPointerGUser",e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void storeDatainSharedPreferences() {
    try {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(NEW_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("CurrentUsername", dataStore.getCurrentUserName());
        editor.putString("CurrentUserId", dataStore.getCurrentUserID());
        editor.commit();
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e)
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this).setMessage("There was an error whil logging in")
                .setTitle("Little Problem here!").setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                removeDatainSharedPreferences();
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }).show();
    }
}

private void removeDatainSharedPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(NEW_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.remove("CurrentUsername");
    editor.remove("CurrentUserId");
    editor.commit();
}


private void initialize() {
    emailInputLayout=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.emailInputLayout);
    emailField=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailField);
    passwordField=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
    passwordInputLayout=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.passwordInputLayout);
    loginButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    emailInputLayout.setHint("Email");
    passwordInputLayout.setHint("Password");
    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
    signupButton=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.signupButton);
    forgotPasswordButton=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.forgotPasswordField);
    googleSignInButton=(SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.googleSignInButton);
    googleSignInButton.setColorScheme(SignInButton.COLOR_AUTO);
    forgotPasswordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,ForgotPasswordActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    SharedPreferences sharePreferences=getSharedPreferences(NEW_PREFS,MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(!sharePreferences.getString("CurrentUsername","null").equals("null")) {
        Log.e("SharedPreferences", sharePreferences.getString("CurrentUsername", "null"));
        Log.e("SharedPreferences",sharePreferences.getString("CurrentUserId",null));
        Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,DialogActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    mGoogleApiClient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();


   if(!isNetworkAvailable())
   {
      snackbar=Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"You are offline",Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
              .setAction("Retry", new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                      if(!isNetworkAvailable())
                          dismissSnackBar();
                      else
                          snackbar.show();
                  }

              });
       snackbar.show();
   }

}

private void dismissSnackBar() {
    snackbar.dismiss();
}


private boolean isNetworkAvailable()
{
    ConnectivityManager manager=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkIngo=manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkIngo!=null&& networkIngo.isConnected();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.e("GoogleApi","Connected");
        getGoogleToken();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.e("GoogleApi",connectionResult.toString());
    if(!connectionResult.hasResolution())
    {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode(),LoginActivity.this,0).show();
    }
    if(connectionResult.isSuccess())
    {
        getGoogleToken();
    }
    try
    {
        connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this,100);
    }
    catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

`

Comment: Paste in relevant code so we can help, please!

Comment: Fine ! Give me a minute !

Comment: Disconnect the `mGoogleApiClient` right after you get login details. As you don't need it further.

Comment: It didn't work.. it uses the same account the next time I try to login. Only when i clear the the cache data in the settings, it prompts to choose the account.

Comment: you need to explicitly signout your user.

Comment: Could u please tell the changes I have to make in the code ?

Comment: @jankigadhiya solution worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

You needed to log out the user from google client.

```
public void signOut() {
   mAuth.signOut();
   mGoogleSignInClient.signOut();
   LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
}
```

Where

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
```

and

```
mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

Answer (score 16):

You have to just clear pre-signed in accounts. To do so, add the following as first line under signIn() function:
mGoogleSignInClient.signOut();

```
 private void signIn() {
    // clearing previous signin caches
       mGoogleSignInClient.signOut();

    //getting the google signin intent
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    //starting the activity for result
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

Comment: but if we dont want to signout then is there any solution?

Comment: because ios have  that option to show list withiut calling signout but android dont have

Comment: @NehaK IF WE DON'T WANT TO SIGN OUT then we won't log out from session. This way we won't have to call signIn() method again.

Comment: Thanks @amitsatputecd7 . I knew this couldn't be something that complicated. I got the exact result I wanted :)

Comment: But, i think, googleSignInClient.signOut() is async call, so we should add onCompleteListener and then call signIn in onCompleteListener

Answer (score 15):

Just add  this `signIn()` method after getting data from the intent.

```
Intent signInIntent=Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect();
```

Comment: A bit for explanation would've been nice.

Comment: @J..S - I wasn't exactly clear on why either, but after seeing it work, the explanation as I understand it is : once you have the firebase user, you are telling GoogleApiClient it shouldn't use any defaults when it goes back to do its authentication again.  I wasn't able to find much tutorial/examples on GoogleApiClient beyond the Javadoc :( - This saved the day, thanks!

Comment: After getting the firebase user, if I call this method, it crashes with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.`. I'm using lib version 11.8.0.

Comment: getting error "* Method is not supported by connectionless client. APIs supporting connectionless client must not call this method.
"

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is to logout the client after you handle your result (onActivityResult). Just make sure that the client is connected before you trigger the logout. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
private void handleGoogleLoginResult(Intent data) {
    if (data != null) {
        // get result from data received
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        int statusCode = result.getStatus().getStatusCode();
        if (result.isSuccess() && result.getSignInAccount() != null) {
            // Signed in successfully

        } 
        // logout
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Without calling SignOut**

Those who needs it in kotlin, this worked for me, I do clear current login cache before a new login request is made

```
/**
 * signInGoogle
 */

private fun signInGoogle() = launch(Dispatchers.IO){

    //init google sigin
    val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(GOOGLE_WEBCLIENT_ID)
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

    val gApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso)
            .build()

    val c = gApiClient.blockingConnect()

    if(c.isSuccess && gApiClient.isConnected){
        gApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect().await()
    }

    val mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(activity, gso)
    val signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent

    launch (Dispatchers.Main){
        // IN MAIN THREAD
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GOOGLE_SIGNIN)
    }.start()

    //start activity

}//end request google login
```

You can view the full source here : https://github.com/transcodium/TNSMoney-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/transcodium/tnsmoney/SocialLoginActivity.kt

for Java users :

```
/**
 * signInGoogle
 */

private void signInGoogle() {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            //init google sigin
            GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id)) // required to get accesstoken
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();

            GoogleApiClient gApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                    .build();

            ConnectionResult c = gApiClient.blockingConnect();

            if (c.isSuccess() && gApiClient.isConnected()) {
                gApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect().await();
            }

            GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(activity, gso);
            Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {


                    //start activit
                    getActivity().startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);


                }
            });

        }
    }).start();


}//end request google login
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: blockingConnect must not be called on the UI thread.

I am getting this exception!

Comment: This worked for me! because I wanted to implemeted switch account feature, and due to signout the token was getting clleared so i could not use that. but this worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am using the Firebase Auth UI, and For me the fix was;

```
AuthUI.getInstance().setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)...
```

When logging in, and then;

```
AuthUI.signOut(context)
```

When Signing out

Answer (score 1):

Simplely workout for me

1>`Activity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {`

2>
    `mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                    .build();`

3>In OnButtonClicked

```
Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 2);
```

4>

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 2) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
                if(acct!=null) {            
                    //Take all data You Want
                    String identifier = acct.getId()+"";                 
                    String displayName = acct.getDisplayName()+"";
                    //After You got your data add this to clear the priviously selected mail
                    mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect();
                }
            }else Log.e("handleSignInResult","Failed ; "+result.getStatus());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I just added "mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect();" after getting Firebase User and it is working.

Comment: Does not work for lib version 11.8.0. Crashes with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.`.

Answer (score 1):

For people in 2K21 Here is what you need to do,

```
private static final int RC_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN = 500;

private void signWithGoogle() {
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient=GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        googleSignInClient.signOut();
        Intent signInIntent = googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);
    }
```

Comment: But, i think, googleSignInClient.signOut() is async call, so we should add onCompleteListener and then call signIn in onCompleteListener

Answer (score 1):

Simple and elegant options to handle is always logout using `GoogleSingInClient` before launch google singin intent.

Using Kotlin you can compose your code like this,

```
private fun signInUsingGoogleAccount() {
        try {
            val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build()
            val googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(requireActivity(), gso)
            googleSignInClient.signOut()

            // Launch Intent
            val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GOOGLE_RESULT_CODE)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

Comment: But, i think, googleSignInClient.signOut() is async call, so we should add onCompleteListener and then call signIn in onCompleteListener

Answer (score 0):

Signout your user using:

```
 Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    // ...
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while searching for a solution using the javascript client, but it might be similar with Android.

`signIn({ prompt: 'select_account' })`

> **select_account**
>
> The authorization server prompts the user to select a Google account. This allows a user who has multiple accounts to select amongst the multiple accounts that they may have current sessions for.

See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthsigninoptions.

Answer (score 0):

You are not revoking user by sign out them use the following to achieve what you need :

Put this code in any activity and call it in sign out button click :

```
private void signOut() {
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
        new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Status status) {
                // ...
            }
        });
```

}

write this in `onCreate()` :

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)
            .build();
```

override this in `onStart()` :

```
 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Reference Link : [Google Developer Page](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect)

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me. !!

```
  @Override
            public void onPause() {
                super.onPause();
                if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResult(Status status) {
                                    // ...
                                }
                            });
                }
                mGoogleApiClient.stopAutoManage(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()));
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

            }
```

if you want to enter again within the Fragment or Activity , you need to recreate these variables

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()))
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), (this))
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `mGoogleSignInClient.signOut();` After succesfully handling sign in.

```
private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                mGoogleSignInClient.signOut();
                updateUI();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        Log.w("SignIn Failed", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
        updateUI(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing `signinActivity` code then just use this line inside the `signInfunction`:

```
private fun signIn() {
    googleSignInClient.signOut()
    val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
}
```

And you can just use a single line in the `signOut` function:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are having any logout functionality. Put the below code just before your logout code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {

       CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
       CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
}
else
{
       CookieSyncManager cookieSyncMngr=CookieSyncManager.createInstance(activity);
       cookieSyncMngr.startSync();
       CookieManager cookieManager=CookieManager.getInstance();
       cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
       cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
       cookieSyncMngr.stopSync();
       cookieSyncMngr.sync();
}
```

Hope this will help.

> EDIT: you can also try replacing you `storeDatainSharedPreferences` method with below code:

```
private void storeDatainSharedPreferences() {
try {

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(NEW_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("CurrentUsername", dataStore.getCurrentUserName());
    editor.putString("CurrentUserId", dataStore.getCurrentUserID());
    editor.commit();
    if(mGoogleApiClient!=null)
          mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
catch (NoSuchElementException e)
{
    new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this).setMessage("There was an error whil logging in")
            .setTitle("Little Problem here!").setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
            removeDatainSharedPreferences();
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }).show();
}}
```

> Explanation : For First solution : It is the code to clear all Cookies
>   related to your application. This can be help full in your situation
>   because you want to clear the previous data which might be stored in
>   Cookies.
>
> Explanation : For Second solution : It is the code which disconnects the mGoogleApiClient. which will be helpful because You have stored the data in sharedPref now you don't need `mGoogleApiClient`.