# How to Disable GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API automatic Sign in after a user logs out

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

When using GoogleSignInApi, GoogleSignInClient, how do I allow users to sign in with a different account?

When a user logs out of the application via the "log out" button and then press the "log in" button (opening the google sign in client), they IMMEDIATELY get logged in with their previously entered google credentials. (There is no prompt for username/password, or ability to choose a different google account.) This effectively means a user can never log into the app with a different account than the one they first entered. Even when I wipe the emulator data entirely and start fresh, it still remembers the credentials and automatically logs in with the same account!

Sign In Code (LoginActivity, OnCreate):

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
```

sign in method

```
private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
```

firebaseAuthWithGoogle (Saves user token in mAuth)

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            //updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(context,"login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            //updateUI(null);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Sign Out Button:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

I believe the problem is related to GoogleSignInOptions.Builder or GoogleApiClient.Builder, but I've been unable to find decent documentation that provides a list of alternative options I can use to configure these items.

All I need is to allow users to log in with a different account! Why does it always log them in with the previous account and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36659753/google-login-uses-same-account-everytime-users-login)

Just add this:

```
mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect();
```

after getting the firebase user

Comment: This resolved the problem! Thanks so much! I've upvoted your answer and his.