# Not showing multiple google accounts in my application?

Tags: android, google-signin

I have Integrated the Google SignIn in android application  When application launch first time and the user clicks on Google button it shows a list of account which is logged in devices.

If the user selects First account user able to get into the application but If I close the application and reopen and clicks on Google button it doesn't show List of accounts.

I want the application to show a list of account each time when a user clicks on the button.

Comment: [how to clear selected google account once logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46504733/5990846)

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227274/how-to-add-programmatically-a-custom-account-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You can Sign out with the [google method](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect).

If you disconnect the User before Sign in you will show the list of accounts.

```html
private void signOut() {
    mGoogleSignInClient.signOut()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```

Don't forget to test before if an user is already connected